# Renaming a Directory with wildcard on Powershell?

Tags: powershell, directory, rename-item-cmdlet

I have a folder that needs to be renamed.

$home/dir1/dir_to_rename_12344343

$value=abcd-1234

I know the beginning pattern of the folder but not the whole name.

I was trying to do something like this

cd $home/dir1

Rename-Item 'dir_to_rename*' '$value'

but it keeps giving me an error.

I am also happy if I can just trim the last few chars of the folder name.

i.e., $home/dir1/dir_to_rename_12344343 --> $home/dir1/dir_to_rename

Comment: What does the error tell you?

Comment: How about running " Get-Help Rename-Item -Full" and look for the required PARAMETERS -eq true and get the right syntax.

Comment: [argument "path" is not valid]. So I added -Path and  now it says [value of argument "path" is not valid]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to get it to work

Get-ChildItem -Path $home/dir1 | Rename-Item -NewName $Value